# does z3 support proving inductive facts at all?

Tags: z3

I understand that z3 cannot verify inductive proofs in general. But I am curious if there is a way to make it check something simple like:

```
; returns the same input list after iterating through each element
(declare-fun iterate ((List Int)) (List Int))

(declare-const l (List Int))

(assert (forall ((l (List Int)))
  (ite (= l nil)
    (= (iterate l) nil)
    (= (iterate l) (insert (head l) (iterate (tail l))))
  )
))

(assert (not (= l (iterate l))))
(check-sat)
```

Right now it just loops forever on my machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Z3 will not make inductive arguments on its own. You can manually give it the induction hypothesis and ask it to finish the proof. This works for your example as follows:

```
(declare-fun iterate ((List Int)) (List Int))

(assert (forall ((l (List Int)))
  (ite (= l nil)
    (= (iterate l) nil)
    (= (iterate l) (insert (head l) (iterate (tail l)))))))

; define list length for convenience in stating the induction hypothesis
(declare-fun length ((List Int)) Int)
(assert (= (length nil) 0))
(assert (forall ((x Int) (l (List Int)))
  (= (length (insert x l)) (+ 1 (length l)))))

(declare-const l (List Int))

; here comes the induction hypothesis: 
; that the statement is true for all lists shorter than l
(assert (forall ((ihl (List Int))) 
  (=> (< (length ihl) (length l))
      (= ihl (iterate ihl)))))

; we now ask Z3 to show that the result follows for l        
(assert (not (= l (iterate l))))
(check-sat)  ; reports unsat as desired
```