# Inductive proofs in theorem provers (Z3, Vampire, with TPTP syntax)

Tags: logic, z3, smt, theorem-proving, logic-programming

I am testing the inductive capabilities of some theorem provers (such as Z3, Alt-Ergo, Vampire etc.) using the TPTP syntax. To my surprise, none of them managed to demonstrate the following simple conjecture:

```
tff(t1, type, (fun: $int > $int )).

tff(ax1, axiom, ( 
    ! [A: $int] : (
        $less(A, 1) => (fun(A) = 123)
    )
)).

tff(ax2, axiom, ( 
    ! [A: $int] : (
        $greatereq(A, 1) => (fun(A) = fun($difference(A, 1))) 
    )
)).

tff(conj1, conjecture, ! [A: $int] : ($greatereq(A, 1) => (fun(A) = 123))).

% END OF SYSTEM OUTPUT
% RESULT: SOT_EWCr1V - Z3---4.8.9.0 says Timeout - CPU = 60.09 WC = 35.47 
% OUTPUT: SOT_EWCr1V - Z3---4.8.9.0 says None - CPU = 0 WC = 0
```

This conjecture can be easily proven by induction, however it does not seem to be the case for the vast majority of theorem provers I have tested this on. Obviously, if I restrict the domain to only one element instead of the whole set of integers, the ATP succeeds because it only needs to check against a limited set of numbers:

```
tff(t1, type, (fun: $int > $int )).

tff(ax1, axiom, ( 
    ! [A: $int] : (
        $less(A, 1) => (fun(A) = 123)
    )
)).

tff(ax2, axiom, ( 
    ! [A: $int] : (
        $greatereq(A, 1) => (fun(A) = fun($difference(A, 1))) 
    )
)).

tff(conj1, conjecture, ! [A: $int] : ((A = 5) => (fun(A) = 123))).

% END OF SYSTEM OUTPUT
% RESULT: SOT_j9liHr - Z3---4.8.9.0 says Theorem - CPU = 0.00 WC = 0.08 
% OUTPUT: SOT_j9liHr - Z3---4.8.9.0 says Proof - CPU = 0.00 WC = 0.09
```

Is this a general limitation of automatic theorem provers? Is there any tool that performs well with induction?

**PS:** You can try it out using the following online tool: https://tptp.org/cgi-bin/SystemOnTPTP

**PS2:** The TPTP syntax manual can be found here: https://www.tptp.org/TPTP/TR/TPTPTR.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. SMT solvers don't do induction out-of-the-box. You can "coax" them to do induction by proving the base case, then posing the induction-hypothesis and have them prove it using quantifiers; but that's usually a fool's errand. SMT solvers are simply not the right choice for doing inductive proofs. Here're some relevant prior discussions on stackoverflow regarding this matter:

- [does z3 support proving inductive facts at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45947230/936310)
- [list concat in z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473042/list-concat-in-z3)
- [How to reverse Z3py Sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70005382/936310)

And many others.

Having said that, the new `define-fun-rec` construct in SMTLib allows for recursive definitions, whose proofs are naturally done by induction. So, I expect the community will be going towards that direction; adding inductive capabilities over time. For instance, see:

- [http://lara.epfl.ch/~reynolds/VMCAI2015-ind/smt-ind-RK.pdf](http://lara.epfl.ch/%7Ereynolds/VMCAI2015-ind/smt-ind-RK.pdf)

for a paper on how to do this properly in an SMT solver. As far as I know CVC5 has incorporated some of these ideas, but expecting out-of-the-box inductive proofs would be naive at this point. (See https://github.com/cvc5/cvc5/issues/1796)

So, long story short: No, SMT solvers don't do induction. You can coax them to do it, and there's recent work that add further capabilities, but a push-button experience is unlikely. If your goal is to reason about recursive definitions and hence you rely on induction, your best bet is to use a semi-automated theorem prover such as Isabelle, Coq, HOL, HOL-Light, ACLL2, Lean, etc.. all of which have strong facilities to do induction. Furthermore they incorporate SMT solvers as "tactics" so you get the best of both worlds in that sense. (i.e., use a manual strategy to dissect your proof to simple enough subgoals, handle induction etc, and ship the rest off to an SMT-solver.)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Some time ago you told me SMT solvers didn't perform well with induction and I sought theorem provers like Alt-Ergo, E Prover, Z3, Vampire, but none of these work. So, what is the difference between a theorem prover and a SMT-solver? I thought all theorem provers could do induction...

Comment: An SMT solver is a particular kind of a theorem prover that provides a push-button experience, but the theories and problems it can handle are limited. (But remain quite useful in practice!) A theorem-prover in the general sense (like Isabelle, ACL2 etc.) can handle much more complicated theories and proofs, but with (often substantial) user guidance.

Comment: Also the distinction is on a sliding time-scale. SMT solvers of today would look rather magical to someone from early 2000's. As time goes on, they become more capable of proving more theorems by themselves; but there are theoretical limitations on what they can handle. A manual theorem prover, on the other hand, can establish any mathematical theorem provided you're willing to put in the work. (Which can be quite substantial.)

Comment: So, should I discard the TPTP syntax? Can Isabelle or HOL make inductive hypothesis if I provide them with a TPTP syntax, or I should learn the native languages they use in order to make these kind of inductive proofs? Because the native language of Isabelle seems quite complicated compared to TPTP.

Comment: I believe Isabelle can read TPTP, though I'm not an expert. (Ask a separate question about that using the tag Isabelle.) Also see here: https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2012/dist/library/HOL/TPTP/TPTP_Parser.html. The final answer really depends on what your exact goals are, but if you're using a particular theorem prover it might be best to use its native language; as posing problems using any other language (TPTP or otherwise) will incur "lost-in-translation" problems. i.e., your experience will be limited to what that translator is capable of.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I also tried Vampire, which claims to support inductive reasoning: "Vampire supports (inductive) reasoning over algebraic data types". See: https://vprover.github.io/ Vampire also fully supports the TPTP syntax. However, I can only get a "Timeout" :( My goal was to automatically transpile pieces of code into a format that can be understood by a theorem prover. This is the case for TPTP, but I don't think it is feasible to transpile code to e.g. Isabelle's native language, because Isabelle's native language has an extremely complex grammar, unlike TPTP.

Comment: The link I included earlier seems to have a TPTP -> HOL parser. I've never used it. That doesn't work for you somehow?

Comment: Thanks. I finally tried running Isabelle on my machine via command line: `./isabelle tptp_isabelle 6000 file.tptp` and it works great with TPTP syntax (specifically TFA: Typed First-order Form with Arithmetic). However, it takes a lot of time even to prove simple statements, and in the ~80% cases it returns GaveUp, or timeout. According to https://www.tptp.org/Seminars/HopingForTheTruth/Evaluations.html#TFA, this is a normal behaviour (reliability in reasoning = 25%). So, I think this is just a limitation of state-of-the-art theorem provers in general, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: For any inductive proof, you'll have to do some work to set it up. Most provers don't attempt it automatically. (I think ACL2 might be an exception, but even then you have to guide it through it.) So, no, I don't think you're missing anything. It's just that your expectations don't match reality in the state-of-art in theorem proving.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out in a comment above, Vampire *does* support induction. However, as is common with other theorem provers, to get Vampire to do what you want is sometimes a little tricky. In this case, to get it to use induction, you have to run with options

```
--mode portfolio --schedule induction
```

With those options set, Vampire finds a proof of the above in next to no time (0.04 seconds on my machine)

The TPTP website does not let you set specific options when running provers, so if you want to try out the above you will have to grab a Vampire release from [here](https://github.com/vprover/vampire/releases) or build from source.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I also tested locally and it works (Status: Theorem)! By the way, do you know other fully-automatic theorem provers or SMT-solvers that support induction like Vampire?

Comment: There are a few, [CVC4](https://cvc4.github.io/), [Zipperposition](https://sneeuwballen.github.io/zipperposition/), [Zeno](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-28756-5_28) and others. As far as I am aware Vampire is one of the stronger provers in this area. There is clearly a need for further research here.